# Camera making strange sound when increasing shutter speed in live view

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, tamron

I recently got a Tamron 90mm macro lens (non vc) but when I use live view with it and decrease the shutter speed I notice a strange noise that sounds like it's coming from the camera.  It doesn't happen without live view enabled and it doesn't happen with any of my other lenses.

Also, in low light situations with this same lens and with live view, I notice bands on the screen.  Again, this doesn't happen with other lenses and it doesn't seem to show up in my pictures.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?  My camera is a rebel t5.

Comment: What are the specific shutter times when it does it and when it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the shutter speed in live view, the camera may change the aperture to give you an accurate preview of the exposure. On some lenses, this movement of the diaphragm could cause noticeable sound.

By changing the shutter speed while looking at the front of your lens, you should be able to observe the movement of the diaphragm and, if there is any, confirm whether or not it is the cause of the sound you are hearing.